# Bixolon SPP-R200III can't connect via bluetooth or WLAN

Tags: printing, bixolon-printer

I have a issue with my printer Bixolon SPP-R200III that does not allow me to connect either by bluetooth or wlan.

When i print the self test it show me that both RF interface are not available.

I need to know how i can enable both interface.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7AQ1.png)

Comment: I'm having the same issue and I think this version does not have Bluetooth or Wi-Fi, the only way to connected is via usb cable which is annoying because it is a propietary usb cable.  Please let me know if you can get the usb cable, this is the part number: K609-00012C

Comment: BTW the version SPP-R200ll <-- is the one without wireless connection, as far as I know spp-R200IIi <--- the 3 i version should have wireless connection

Answer (score 1):

try factory resetting and check again
https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1558802/Bixolon-Spp-L310.html?page=10

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).